# Macbook SSD not showing up in Disk Utility

Tags: macos

I have an early 2015 Macbook Pro which was on Catalina and got stuck in a boot loop after I let it update overnight. So, I decided to install a fresh copy and proceeded to erase the HDD. Now instead of erasing the Data Volume, I deleted the whole "Volume Group". I then saw some posts where they advise against it but that train has left the station..

Now my HDD is not showing up neither in the disk utility not in diskutil. The internet recovery is trying to install Yosemite since that was the default but it's failing to find the destination drive. Found an old Time machine backup as well, same issue though ..

Can't go out to a technician due to the lockdown.. Is there any solution?

Comment: Booting to 'regular' internet recovery Cmd/opt/R should restore to 'latest' OS Cmd/Opt/Shift/R to restore to 'initial' OS. Please clarify.

Comment: I can't boot to the regular recovery. The keys take me straight to internet recovery

Comment: Re-read what I wrote. Cmd/R is internal recovery, the other two are both internet, but to different end results.

Comment: Oh. didn't know that. I'm trying Cmd/R now

Comment: @Tetsujin mate. You're a life saver! Thanks a heap :)